# printing out the values of a hash coming from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash called `sales_hash` that I am printing out.  Each hash has a key called `sku` that matches a hash inside the array of `array_items`.  I get the hash out of the array and am trying to print the values of the hash based on the key which is `:item` but I keep getting an error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
sales_hash.take(10).each do |a, b|
  temp_hash = array_items.select{|array_items| array_items[:sku] == a}
  puts temp_hash
  puts "Sku is #{a} the amount sold is #{b} the name of the book is #{temp_hash[:price]}"
end
```

The line `#{temp_hash[:item]}"` keeps giving me an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Do: `puts temp_hash.inspect` and see what you are getting inside the `temp_hash`

Comment: @DJ the error message is rb:59:in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam, I get a hash of items   [{:item=>["cornish_heath"], :price=>24.33, :sku=>236131}]

Comment: That's not a hash, that's an array of hashes.

Comment: How do I get the hash out of the array?

Comment: In your partiulcar case: `temp_hash[0][:price]` would work. Try this and let me know!

Comment: Thanks, post your answer below so I can accept your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93932/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-aaron).

Comment: @Aaron I have posted my answer as per our discussion that solved your problem. Please let me know if you have any other question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `temp_hash` is actually an array.

From the [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

select -> Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.

And you can't access and array like this: array[:key].

Answer (score 1):

As your `temp_hash` is an array, so you can access the expected hash like this:

```
temp_hash[0] # this will give you the expected hash data
```

And, then you can access the required key inside the hash (e.g. `price`):

```
temp_hash[0][:price]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `temp_hash` is an array, and you're sure that there's only one item inside that array, the proper way to get the content of temp_hash is using "first" like this:

`#{temp_hash.first[:price]}`